# How to use `emit_struct` and `emit_struct_field` to serialize a custom struct?

Tags: serialization, rust

I've read valve's [JSON Serialization in Rust, Part 1](http://valve.github.io/blog/2014/08/25/json-serialization-in-rust-part-1/) and try to run the code in the blogpost. The most complicated part is do a custom serialization for a custom struct.

I update the snippet so it can run on newest Rust nightly:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::{json, Encodable, Encoder};

struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
}

impl Encodable for Person {
    fn encode<S: Encoder>(&self, s: &mut S) -> Result<(), S::Error> {
        match *self {
            Person { name: ref p_name, age: ref p_age, } => {
                s.emit_struct("Person", 0, |s| {
                    try!(s.emit_struct_field( "name", 0, |s| p_name.encode(s)));
                    try!(s.emit_struct_field( "age", 1, |s| p_age.encode(s)));
                    try!(s.emit_struct_field( "summary", 2, |s| {
                        (format!("Nice person named {}, {} years of age", p_name, p_age)).encode(s)
                    }));
                    Ok(())
                })
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        name: "John Doe".to_string(),
        age: 33,
    };
    println!("{}" , json::encode(&person).unwrap());
}
```

The output of above is `{}`, but the correct result should be:

`{"age":33,"name":"John Doe","summary":"Nice person named John Doe, 33 years of age"}`

I want to know how to use `Encodable` trait to serialize a custom struct in right way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your tutorial is out-of-date. It says

> We call emit_struct on our encoder and pass it 3 arguments: the name of the struct, current index and an anonymous function(aka lambda). The name of the struct is not used; **current index is not used** too.

But [the code says](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize/blob/031333c08d4819aa36127f1a4070e3efcc2341d7/src/json.rs#L732-L737)

```rust
fn emit_struct<F>(&mut self, _: &str, len: usize, f: F) -> EncodeResult<()> where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Encoder<'a>) -> EncodeResult<()>,
{
    if self.is_emitting_map_key { return Err(EncoderError::BadHashmapKey); }
    if len == 0 {
        try!(write!(self.writer, "{{}}"));
```

So the argument has changed from an *index* to a *length*, and it's now meaningful. Here's your example working:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::{json, Encodable, Encoder};

struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
}

impl Encodable for Person {
    fn encode<S: Encoder>(&self, s: &mut S) -> Result<(), S::Error> {
        s.emit_struct("Person", 1, |s| {
            try!(s.emit_struct_field("name",    0, |s| self.name.encode(s)));
            try!(s.emit_struct_field("age",     1, |s| self.age.encode(s)));
            try!(s.emit_struct_field("summary", 2, |s| {
                let summary = format!("Nice person named {}, {} years of age", self.name, self.age);
                summary.encode(s)
            }));
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        name: "John Doe".to_string(),
        age: 33,
    };
    println!("{}" , json::encode(&person).unwrap());
}
```

Note that I also removed the crazy gyrations to destructure `self` and just access the properties directly.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Rust and rustc-serialize is really not well-documented. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You problem is with the `emit_struct(..)` call.

The prototype of this function is:

```rust
fn emit_struct<F>(&mut self, name: &str, len: usize, f: F)
    -> Result<(), Self::Error>
    where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
```

Here, `len` is the number of fields of your struct. Bu you are setting it to `0`, so the JSON dictionary generated has 0 fields.

Changing it to 3 gives this output:

```rust
{"name":"John Doe","age":33,"summary":"Nice person named John Doe, 33 years of age"}
```

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial is totally out of date.